# Функция высшего порядка

Tags: javascript, функции

Нужно создать две функции:

Первая принимает массив и колбэк;
А вторая функция(колбэк) обрабатывает каждый элемент массива.

Первая возвращает строку `"Value class:"` и обработанный массив:

```
firstFunc(['JS', 'is', 'beautiful'], secondFunc)->'New value: JSIsBeautiful'
```

У меня пока только такой код:

```js
let each = function (arr, callback) {
    let i, length = arr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 1) {
        callback(arr[i], i, arr);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = ["JS", "is", "beautiful"];

function firstFunc(array, callback) {
  console.log("Value class:", array);
  callback(array);
}

firstFunc(arr, function(arr) {
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var t = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1);
    str += t;
  }
  console.log("New value:", str);
})
```

Comment: Там еще первые буквы нужно заглавными сделать

Comment: @Darth ага, не обратил внимание. Исправил

Answer (score 2):

```js
const secondFunc = word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
const firstFunc = (arr, cb) => `New value: ${arr.reduce((res,el) => res + cb(el))}`;

console.log(firstFunc(['JS', 'is', 'beautiful'], secondFunc)) // -> 'New value: JSIsBeautiful'
```